# Parameters will not pass in the child class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

When I'm trying to create a job, it will show "company must exist", c_name and company_id will not pass in the `views/jobs/_form`

#### Migrations

```
class CreateJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :jobs do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      t.string :c_name
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :company_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :c_name
      t.text :c_description
      t.integer :user_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

#### Models

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :companies
  has_many :jobs
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to:user
  has_many:jobs
end
```

#### Jobs controller

```
def show
end

def new
  @job = current_user.jobs.build       
end

def create
  job_attrs = jobs_params.except(:c_name)
  job_attrs[:c_name] = Company.find_by(id: jobs_params[:c_name])
  @job = current_user.jobs.build(job_attrs)

  if @job.save
    flash[:success]= "success"
    redirect_to @job
  else
    flash[:error]=@job.errors.full_messages
    render "new"
  end
end

def jobs_params
  params
    .require(:job)
    .permit(:title, 
            :description, 
            :c_name, 
            :category_id, 
            :image, 
            :jobclosedate, 
            :company_id)
end
```

#### jobs/_form

```
<%= simple_form_for(@job,validation:true ,html: { mutlipart: true, class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title, label: "Job Title", input_html: { class: "form-control"} %>
  <%= f.input :description, label: "Job Description", input_html: { class: "form-control" } %>
  <%= f.input :c_name, label: "Your Company", input_html: { class: "form-control" } %>
  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, {promt: "Choose a category" } %>
```

When I'm try to create a job, it will return a "company must exist" validation error, `c_name` and `company_id` will not pass in the `views/jobs/_form`.

Could you please help me to sort it out. It seems the create action has an issue. I'm new to Ruby, please explain how I can sort this out.

Comment: Can you add the actual error from the server logs?

Comment: Also - what is the `render partial` for the form look like? You need to pass any variables in as `locales`

Answer (score 1):

I see you are not picking a company from a select, but just writing the name. And in your controller you are looking for the company, by name. This approach is not very good, as the user can write names of companies that do not exist, or with spelling errors. You could use a select tag and pass the company_id.

The correct way to do it is:

**Migrations:**

```
class CreateJobs < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :jobs do |t|
      t.string :title
      t.text :description
      #t.string :c_name REMOVE THIS. YOU DON'T NEED THE COMPANY NAME HERE.
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :company_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateCompanies < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
    create_table :companies do |t|
      t.string :c_name
      t.text :c_description
      t.integer :user_id
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**Models**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

  has_many :companies
  has_many :jobs
end

class Job < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :category
  belongs_to :company
end

class Company < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to:user
  has_many:jobs
end
```

**Jobs controller**

```
def new
  @job = current_user.jobs.build       
end

def create
  @job = current_user.jobs.build(job_params)
  if @job.save
    flash[:success]= "success"
    redirect_to @job
  else
    flash[:error]=@job.errors.full_messages
    render "new"
  end
end

def jobs_params
  params.require(:job).permit(:title, 
        :description, 
        :category_id, 
        :image, 
        :jobclosedate, 
        :company_id)
end
```

**jobs/_form**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@job,validation:true ,html: { multipart: true, class: 'form-horizontal'}) do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :title, label: "Job Title", input_html: { class: "form-control"} %>
  <%= f.input :description, label: "Job Description", input_html: { class: "form-control" } %>
  <!-- Removed the c_name field -->
  <%= f.collection_select :category_id, Category.all, :id, :name, { prompt: "Choose a category" } %>
  <%= f.collection_select :company_id, current_user.companies.all, :id, :name, {prompt: "Choose a company" } %>
<% end %>
```

**Note:** Your job belongs to a user. An it also belongs to a company. And a company belongs to a user. So the user in the job may not be needed (you can access through job.company.user (unless job.user means other concept and it's not the same as the company user)

**Previous approach**

Anyway, if you want to keep using the company name in the view you must do come changes in the controller. The code you are using to search the company by name is wrong. You need to get the company_id to put in the params (and the in the Job record), but you are just adding the whole company record.

Instead of

```
job_attrs[:c_name] = Company.find_by(id: jobs_params[:c_name])
```

You should write

```
company = current_user.companies.find_by(name: jobs_params[:c_name])
if company
  job_attrs[:company_id] = company.id
else
  # Error. Do not create job...
end
```

Lastly, you don't need the company name in your Job table (just remove c_name). If you still want to use c_name in the view to get the company, just define an attribute in the model (but don't save it in the table).

```
attr_accessor :c_name;
```

Comment: thank you very much,but there are having this error, NoMethodError in JobsController#create
undefined method `id' for nil:NilClass
Extracted source (around line #26):    
   job_attrs = jobs_params.except(:company_id)
   
   job_attrs[:company_id] = Company.find_by(id: jobs_params[:c_name]).id

Comment: You must find the company by name (not id). And you must also check if it was found. I updated the answer

Comment: now issue is like this ,Unpermitted parameter: :companies
  Company Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."c_name" IS NULL LIMIT ?  [["LIMIT", 1]]
No template found for JobsController#create, rendering head :no_content

Comment: it wii not search company id based on the particular user_id

Comment: I updated the answer with the correct solution (in my point of view). Passing the company_id from the view.

Comment: Unpermitted parameter: :companies
  Company Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."user_id" = ? AND "companies"."c_name" IS NULL LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
No template found for JobsController#create, rendering head :no_content

Comment: I removed the company find by name in the new approach. You still want to use the search by name?

Comment: Why do you need c_name?. Is this the company name? You already have in the job through job.company.name. It's not good to have the company name in the job. Just the company_id. You must remove the c_name from the table, from the view and from the job_params (I did in my answer)

Comment: but now ,Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"Yrd4IUWHppOUWNWvCypZrhpeaseb4VyKTdRTp5zEnDO9yRQl/wfef1zs4VCvK4tnRO7cE5OcmHNSIFW+IX10Ig==", "job"=>{"title"=>"job job", "description"=>"aaaaaaaaa aaaaaaaaaa", "category_id"=>"1", "jobclosedate"=>"02/13/2018"}, "commit"=>"Create Job"}
  User Load (0.5ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."id" = ? ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT ?  [["id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  Company Load (0.0ms)  SELECT  "companies".* FROM "companies" WHERE "companies"."user_id" = ? AND "companies"."c_name" IS NULL LIMIT ?  [["user_id", 1], ["LIMIT", 1]]

Comment: my current code is like this, company = current_user.companies.find_by(name: jobs_params[:c_name])
if company
  job_attrs[:company_id] = company.id,@job = current_user.jobs.build( job_attrs)
  if @job.save

Comment: You don't need this find anymore. I have removed it from the answer (unless you keep using the previous approach which I do not recommend)

Comment: that's great, first i was confuse, now i got that, thanks a lot,  you did such a great job

Comment: how may i display the company name  show.html.haml page?

Comment: In jobs/show page? You set `@job` in the controller and use `@job.company.name` in the view